Filter in a user-friendly way
I have a report that provides the user with a workflow to get to the information they need.  To avoid displaying the downstream visualizations before the user has provided enough information, I have created a measure in my semantic model...
One State Selected = IF(CALCULATE(
HASONEVALUE( 'State'[State Abbreviation] ),
ALLSELECTED( 'State'[State Abbreviation] )
), 1, 0)

...then I use it on the visualization in my report...
One State Selected
is 1
But this breaks as I work my way through the workflow.  I think I have identified the problem.  For one of the slicers I want to display the state abbreviation and name to enable the user to identify the correct state, then filter downstream by the state abbreviation.  If I do this in a slicer viz, it is presented as a hierarchy and the user must expand every state abbreviation manually to see the names.  So I thought I would use a table.  But the table and the slicer are behaving differently.  If I use a table the next table I click makes One State Selected = 0.  If I use a slicer the values work out, but the user experience is horrible.
In the tool I am trying to migrate reports from, it's a trivial matter to present the user with a value from one column (state name) and use the value from a different column (state abbreviation) as the filter value.  Is this possible in Power BI?
Is there a way to configure a slicer to filter by one value but present different or additional detail to the user?
Is there a way to configure the filtering action or the visualization relationships in a way that will allow me to filter using a table?
One thing to note here:  I'm using State as an example.  In the data I am working with, multiple codes can be associated with the same descriptive value.  So it is best to present to the user both the code and the description (and maybe other details) but still filter only on the code.
